# move image angle direction on google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, angle, direction

I try this code for plotting data on google map
This code is generate table through jquery and plotting data on google map and also on load small content window is display on every marker

now i want to move image accordint to  directions

data in table is

```
No  Status Datetime                   Longitude Latitude    Direction
BF  5     2016-09-23 15:08:38.000    65.1197    34.95387      9
BR  5     2016-09-23 15:17:26.000    65.068758  34.8639578    30
```

i try this code but this is not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

       var ID = '<%=Session["ID"]%>';
        var RegNo = '';
        var Status = '';
        var latit = '';
        var longi = '';
        var angle;

            var obj = {};
            obj.ID = ID;

            getdata(obj);
            return false;

    });

    function getdata(obj) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "home.aspx/info",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",

            data: "{'id':'" + obj.ID + "'}",

            datatype: "json",


            success: function (result) {

                var d = JSON.parse(result.d).response;

                console.log(JSON.parse(result.d).response);

                console.log(JSON.stringify(result.d).response);

                $("#tabledata").empty();
                if (d.length > 0) {
                    $("#tabledata").append(
 "<thead><tr><th>No</th><th>DateTime</th><th>Status</thth>Longitude</th><th>Latitude</th<tr></thead>");

                    for (var i = 0; i < d.length - 1; i++) {
                        if (d[i] !== null) {
                            $("#tabledata").append("<tbody><tr><td>" +
                               d[i][0] + "</td> <td>" +
                               d[i][1] + "</td> <td>" +
                               d[i][2] + "</td> <td>" +
                               d[i][3] + "</td> <td>" +
                               d[i][4] + "</td></tr></tbody>");
                            Status = d[i][2];
                            debugger;
                            No = d[i][0];
                            latit = d[i][4];
                            longi = d[i][3];
                            angle = d[i][7];
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $("#tabledata").hide();
                }

                alert(d.length);
                var map;
                var image;
                debugger;
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.0895898, 77.0998546);
                debugger;
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

                for (i = 0; i < d.length - 1; i++) {
                    var data = d[i]
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(d[i][4], d[i][3]);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng,
                        icon: "/images/car.png",
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Click me'

                    });

                     ({
                        content: 'window'
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker, data);
                    });
                    infowindow.open(map, marker, data);
                }
                for (i = 0; i < d.length - 1; i++) {
                    debugger;
                    if (d[i][7] == 0) {
                        image = "images/google/0.png";
                    }
                    else if (d[i][7] > 0 & d[i][7] <= 15) {
                        img = "images/google/15.png";

                    }
                    else if (d[i][7] > 15 & d[i][7] <= 30) {
                        img = "images/google/30.png";

                    }
                    else if (d[i][7] > 30 & d[i][7] <= 45) {
                        img = "images/google/45.png";

                    }
                    else if (d[i][7] > 45 & d[i][7] <= 60) {
                        img = "images/google/60.png";

                    }
                           },
            error: function (error) {

                alert("error")
            }
        });
    }


</script>
```

Comment: ? any solutions???????????